# Strange behavior of uniq on darwin shells

Tags: shell, darwin

I've used 'uniq -d -c file' in many shell scripts on linux machines, and it works.
On my MAC (OS X 10.6.7 with developer tools installed) it doesn't seems to work:

```
$ uniq -d -c testfile.txt 
usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]]
```

It would be nice if anyone could checks this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's right there in the `Usage` message. `[ -c | -d | -u]` means you can use *one* of those possibilities, not two.

Since OSX is based on BSD, you can check that [here](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/uniq.1.html) or, thanks to Ignacio, the more Apple-specific one [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uniq.1.html).

If you want to achieve a similar output, you could use:

```
do_your_thing | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 '
```

which will strip out all those coalesced lines that have a count of one.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uniq.1.html

Comment: @former, that _is_ annoying. I suspect that the software is collapsing under the weight of philosophy when trying to figure out how to both output only duplicated lines as well as only unique lines :-) Sounds very much like a bug based on the usage.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "-d ... doesn't make much sense when you're coalescing them with a count". I believe your reasoning is that because each duplicate line will be output only once, the count for each line will end up being 1. This is an incorrect interpretation. The OSX manpage states that the flag "-c" shall "precede each output line with the count of the number of times the line occurred in the input, followed by a single space." The count depends on the input, not the output. Unfortunately it seems that Apple has sided with this incorrect interpretation.

Comment: @someguy, since it's Apple's software (BSD's really but their man page states the same thing as Apple's), I think you'll find theirs is the _correct_ interpretation :-) Anyhow, the usage message is clear: it allows _one_ option from the group `{-c,-d,-u}` (aforementioned bug allowing both d and u notwithstanding). Since my supposition wasn't really a central part of my answer, I'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this  `awk` solution

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]>1){ print i ,a[i] } }' file
```