# Find duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?

Tags: file, count, find, duplicates, lines

Suppose I have a file similar to the following:

```
123 
123 
234 
234 
123 
345
```

I would like to find how many times '123' was duplicated, how many times '234' was duplicated, etc.
So ideally, the output would be like:

```
123  3 
234  2 
345  1
```

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Answer (score 1002, accepted):

Assuming there is one number per line:

```
sort <file> | uniq -c
```

You can use the more verbose `--count` flag too with the GNU version, e.g., on Linux:

```
sort <file> | uniq --count
```

Comment: This is what I do however algorithmically this is doesnt seem to be the most efficient approach (O(n log n)*avg_line_len where n is number of lines). I'm working on files that are several gigabytes large, so performance is a key issue. I wonder whether there is a tool that does just the counting in a single pass using a prefix tree (in my case strings often have common prefixes) or similar, that should do the trick in O(n) * avg_line_len. Does anyone know such a commandline tool?

Comment: An additional step is to pipe the output of that into a final 'sort -n' command. That will sort the results by which lines occur most often.

Comment: If you want to only print duplicate lines, use 'uniq -d'

Comment: If you want to again sort the result, you may use `sort` again like: `sort <file> | uniq -c | sort -n`

Comment: if @DmitrySandalov hat not mentioned `-d` I would have taken `…  | uniq -c | grep -v '^\s*1' ` (`-v` means inverse regexp, that denies matches (not verbose, not version :))

Comment: by the way, you can use `-c -d` and print duplicate lines *and* the count

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the first part of a text file? My logs have timestamps, so I want to ignore the first n chars.

Comment: @Brunis https://stackoverflow.com/a/339941/7030591

Answer (score 570):

This will **print duplicate lines only**, with counts:

```
sort FILE | uniq -cd
```

or, with GNU long options (on Linux):

```
sort FILE | uniq --count --repeated
```

on [BSD and OSX you have to use grep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699355/2093341) to filter out unique lines:

```
sort FILE | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 '
```

For the given example, the result would be:

```
  3 123
  2 234
```

---

If you want to **print counts for all lines** including those that appear only once:

```
sort FILE | uniq -c
```

or, with GNU long options (on Linux):

```
sort FILE | uniq --count
```

For the given input, the output is:

```
  3 123
  2 234
  1 345
```

---

In order to **sort the output** with the most frequent lines on top, you can do the following (to get all results):

```
sort FILE | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

or, to get only duplicate lines, most frequent first:

```
sort FILE | uniq -cd | sort -nr
```

on OSX and BSD the final one becomes:

```
sort FILE | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 ' | sort -nr
```

Comment: Good point with the --repeated or -d option. So much more accurate than using "|grep 2" or similar!

Comment: How I can modify this command to retrieve all lines whose repetition count is more than 100 ?

Comment: @Black_Rider Adding `| sort -n` or `| sort -nr` to the pipe will sort the output by repetition count (ascending or descending respectively). This is not what you're asking but I thought it might help.

Comment: @Black_Rider awk seems able to do all kind of calculations: in your case you could do `| awk '$1>100'`

Comment: @fionbio `sort FILE | uniq -cd` should work on OSX too

Comment: @fionbio Looks like [you can't use -c and -d together on OSX uniq](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uniq.1.html). Thanks for pointing out. You can [use grep to filter out unique lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5699355/2093341): `sort FILE | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 '`

Comment: Piping to `awk '$1>1'` seems a lot better than `grep -v '^ *1 '` to me. It allows us to change the minimum duplicate count with ease and works flawlessly even on macOS. :)

Comment: `sort FILE | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 ' | sort -nr` is beautiful!

Comment: on OSX you can use `uniq -d` if you don't care about the count

Answer (score 77):

To find and count duplicate lines in multiple files, you can try the following command:

```
sort <files> | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

or:

```
cat <files> | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 37):

Via [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```sh
awk '{dups[$1]++} END{for (num in dups) {print num,dups[num]}}' data
```

In `awk 'dups[$1]++'` command, the variable `$1` holds the entire contents of column1 and square brackets are array access. So, for each 1st column of line in `data` file, the node of the array named `dups` is incremented.

And at the end, we are looping over `dups` array with `num` as variable and print the saved *numbers* first then their number of duplicated value by `dups[num]`.

Note that your input file has spaces on end of some lines, if you clear up those, you can use `$0` in place of `$1` in command above :)

Comment: Isn't this a bit of overkill considering that we have `uniq`?

Comment: `sort | uniq` and the awk solution have quite different performance & resource trade-offs: if the files are large and the number of different lines is small, the awk solution is a lot more efficient. It is linear in the number of lines and the space usage is linear in the number of different lines. OTOH, the awk solution needs to keeps all the different lines in memory, while (GNU) sort can resort to temp files.

Answer (score 19):

**In Windows, using "Windows PowerShell"**, I used the command mentioned below to achieve this

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Group-Object | Select Name, Count
```

Also, we can use the where-object Cmdlet to filter the result

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select Name, Count
```

Comment: can you delete all occurrences of the duplicates except the last one...without changing the sort order of the file?

Comment: Similarly to below, you can, of course, also `sort`, using `...| Sort -Top 15 -Descending Count | Select Name`

Answer (score 19):

To find duplicate counts, use this command:

```
sort filename | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've got access to a standard Unix shell and/or cygwin environment:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < yourfile | sort | uniq -d -c
       ^--space char
```

Basically: convert all space characters to linebreaks, then sort the tranlsated output and feed that to uniq and count duplicate lines.

Comment: I guess this solution was tailored to a specific case of your own?  i.e. you've got a list of words separated by spaces or newlines only.
If it's only a list of numbers separated by newlines (no spaces) it will work fine there, but obviously your solution will treat lines containing spaces differently.