# Regex/Algorithm to find 'n' repeated lines in a file

Tags: regex, algorithm, count, find, duplicates

I am looking for an advanced version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated).

Basically, if I have a file with text:

```
abc
ghi
fed
jkl
abc
ghi
fed
```

I want the output to be:(for `n=3`)

```
Duplicated Lines
abc
ghi
fed
Times = 2
```

Comment: What kind of language you are using?

Comment: I am not looking for a language specific solution, although, for the sake of your question let's say Python.

Comment: @s4san Do the lines in the output have to be in the order in which they appear in the input? In your example, would it be bad if you got `abc\nfed\nghi\n` in the output? If not, you could simply use the UNIX utilities `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: @Jubobs The output needs to be ordered as I have to extract the duplicates.

Comment: How much memory is available compared to the size of the file? If you don't have an actual file right now, estimate worst case scenarios.

Comment: @s4san `uniq` would remove the duplicates for you (if you apply `sort` beforehand).

Comment: @Jubobs I have to preserve the non-duplicate lines.

Comment: What if matches overlap, do you want to count them? For instance, if I can represent lines as characters as an example, with N=3, how many duplicates would this string produce? `ABABABA`?

Comment: @s4san You write: *I have to preserve the non-duplicate lines*. Yet that's not what the output of your example reflects: it only lists duplicate lines.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen A string with repeated characters would be considered a single line(ABABABA = 1line, since there is no `CR`) and the goal would be to find another line that matches the same.

Comment: I understand that, please think of each character as one line since it is hard to write lines in a comment. If you had two lines that occurred interleaved like that, how many duplicates would you have?

Comment: @Jubobs the output is just a listing of a particular instance of duplicated lines and not the actual file. I can run a simple search after receiving this output to extract all duplicated lines.

Comment: What does `n=3` mean?

Comment: @s4san Then what are you looking for, exactly? Your question is making less and less sense...

Comment: @sln `n` represents number of lines to search for, which could be duplicated in the rest of the file.

Comment: He is asking how to efficiently find sequences of lines that occur more than once. The 3 lines abc, ghi, fed, in that order, occur twice in the example, thus the final output. His question is poorly worded, I agree, but that is what I understood the question as.

Comment: In a program like Python I would gather `n` and `n` lines and stuff them into tuples and use those as keys to a dictionary to find and count duplicates. I would basically read the first `n` lines, create a tuple of that, then remove the first line and read the next line, create a new tuple of the `n` lines I now have, and repeat.

Comment: @Jubobs as the question says, I just want to find `n` lines in a given file that have duplicates(same `n` lines repeated) in the rest of the file, and print the `n` lines that have duplicates.

Comment: Ok, well in that case, or any case, it can't be done with regex because regex can't count, or doesn't make a count available to you. There is an exception - this can be done in Perl regex with _code construct_. Or, possibly using Dot-Net's _Capture Collection_ within a lookahead.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Assuming your example has multiple lines, the output would be `No duplicate lines` because line with `AB` has repeated thrice but has not done so, more than once.

Comment: I don't understand then, `AB` is not one line, it is two lines, `A` and `B`. As such I would think that `A,B,A` would occur twice.

Comment: The other issue with this is there could be overlap (if n > 1) of duplicates. But,  what are you going to do with that info. In regex, assuming you can get a count, you would consume a single line at a time, using lookaheads to find dups starting at that line, next line, next, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is splitting your text based on your `n` then count the number of your elements that all is depending this counting you can use some data structures that use hash-table like dictionary in python that is much efficient for such tasks.

The task is that you create a dictionary that keeps the keys unique and then loop over the list of splitted text and increase the count of each item every time you see a duplicate.

At last you'll have a dictionary contain the unique items with those count as the values of dictionary.

Some langs like python provides good tools like `Counter` for count the elements within an iterable and `islice` for slicing and iterable that returns a generator and is very efficient for long iterables :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import islice

>>> s="""abc
... ghi
... fed
... jkl
... abc
... ghi
... fed"""
>>> sp=s.split()
>>> Counter('\n'.join(islice(sp,i,i+3)) for i in range(len(sp)))
Counter({'abc\nghi\nfed': 2, 'fed': 1, 'jkl\nabc\nghi': 1, 'ghi\nfed': 1, 'fed\njkl\nabc': 1, 'ghi\nfed\njkl': 1})
```

Or you can do it custom :

```
>>> a=['\n'.join(sp[i:i+3] for i in range(len(sp))]
>>> a
['abc\nghi\nfed', 'ghi\nfed\njkl', 'fed\njkl\nabc', 'jkl\nabc\nghi', 'abc\nghi\nfed', 'ghi\nfed', 'fed']
>>> d={}
>>> for i in a:
...    if i in d:
...       d[i]+=1
...    else :
...       d[i]=1
... 
>>> d
{'fed': 1, 'abc\nghi\nfed': 2, 'jkl\nabc\nghi': 1, 'ghi\nfed': 1, 'fed\njkl\nabc': 1, 'ghi\nfed\njkl': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: So, the keys here would be lines and I start the search with n = 1 and  find all duplicates of n=1, then do a recursion by incrementing n?

Comment: @s4san No you split your text based on `n`

Comment: Can you edit your answer, it says 'test' so I got confused :)

Comment: @s4san Oops sorry, just a typo!

Answer (score 1):

So, something like this (in perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen; 
my @order; 

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
   chomp ( $line ); 
   push ( @order, $line ) unless $seen{$line}++; 

}

foreach my $element ( @order ) { 
    print "$element, $seen{$element}\n" if $seen{$element} > 1;
}

__DATA__
abc
ghi
fed
jkl
abc
ghi
fed
```

This can turn into a shorter snippet by:

```
perl -e 'while ( <> ) { push ( @order, $_ ) unless $seen{$_}++; } for (@order) {print if $seen{$_} > 1}' myfile
```

Comment: Its too easy using  hashes. I think the OP wants a painful solution.

Comment: Well, I can always onelinerify it to make it proper "write only" perl.