# Find duplicate line starts in a text file

Tags: count, find, duplicates, lines

I found this answer ([Find duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated)) while searching and it solves the issue of duplicate lines, but I have a peculiar issue.

I have a need to find duplicates of lines that have the same line beginnings.

For example:

```
2501,3,0,1,0,1457695800
2501,3,0,1,0,1457789340
2502,3,0,0,0,1457695800
2502,3,0,0,0,1457789340
2503,3,0,0,0,1457789340
2504,3,0,0,0,1457789340 
2505,3,0,0,0,1457789340
```

In the CSV data above, `2501` and `2502` would be duplicates if the timestamp was not there.

Is there a way to find them as duplicates by considering only the first 5 fields i.e. excluding timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer by tacking a bunch of commands together:

```
cat my_file.csv | perl -p -i -n -e 's/^(.*),[0-9]{10}.+?$/$1/' | sort | uniq -d
```

So basically, the steps are:

1. use `cat` to get the contents of the file
2. pipe it to perl and use a regular expression to get only the capturing group (in this case, everything before the timestamp)
3. pipe the output to `sort` which will sort the content
4. use `uniq` with `-d` switch to find line duplicates

If you like you can also output the result to file:

```
cat my_file.csv | perl -p -i -n -e 's/^(.*),[0-9]{10}.+?$/$1/' | sort | uniq -d > line_duplicates.txt
```

Hope this helps.