# How to find duplicate lines in a file?

Tags: sorting, uniq

I have an input file with foillowing data:

```
line1
line2
line3
begin
line5
line6
line7
end
line9
line1
line3
```

I am trying to find all the duplicate lines , I tried

```
sort filename | uniq -c
```

but does not seem to be working for me :

It gives me :

```
  1 begin
  1 end
  1 line1
  1 line1
  1 line2
  1 line3
  1 line3
  1 line5
  1 line6
  1 line7
  1 line9
```

the question may seem duplicate as [Find duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated)
but nature of input data is different .

Please suggest .

Comment: If I try to reproduce your problem, I get lines like `2 line3`, so probably there is a problem with spacing after `line1` etc in the source file.

Comment: Thanks Will there was a spacing problem indeed , I removed the space and result is OK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this:

```
sort filename | uniq -d
man uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`sort -u file`

or

`awk '!a[$0]++' file`

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to modify the standard de-dupe code just a tiny bit to account for this:

if you want **unique copy of the duplicates**, then it's very much same idea:

```
  {m,g}awk 'NF~ __[$_]++' FS='^$'
  {m,g}awk '__[$_]++==!_'
```

If you want **every copy** printed for **duplicates**, then whenever the condition yields **true** *for the first time*, print 2 copies of it, plus print new matches along the way.

Usually it's waaaaaaaaay faster to `first de-dupe`, `then sort`, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file name as the first argument to this script.

Example: `find-dupes.sh name.ext`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check if a file name is provided
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [file]"
    exit 1
fi

# File to check for duplicates
file="$1"

# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "Error: File not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Finding duplicates
duplicates=$(sort "$file" | uniq -d)

if [ -z "$duplicates" ]; then
    printf "\n%s\n" "No duplicates were found in $file."
else
    printf "\n%s\n\n" "Duplicate lines in $file:"
    echo "$duplicates"
fi
```