# Search duplicate lines in a file, count it and which location (line number) without sorting it?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I've been reading about similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated), however the answer was provided without line number.

```
[root@test ~]# cat -n file 
     1  123 
     2  123 
     3  234 
     4  234 
     5  123 
     6  345
[root@test ~]#

[root@test ~]# sort file | uniq -c
      3 123 
      2 234 
      1 345
[root@test ~]#
```

What I'm looking for is something like [this](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/remove-duplicate-lines/), but in Linux shell script (preferable), or any other scripting solutions.

**Output provided by textmechanic.com**

```
( 2 dupe of 1 ): 123 
( 4 dupe of 3 ): 234 
( 5 dupe of 1 ): 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($1 in a) printf "( %d dupe of %d ): %s\n", NR, a[$1], $1; else a[$1] = NR}' file
```

```
( 2 dupe of 1 ): 123
( 4 dupe of 3 ): 234
( 5 dupe of 1 ): 123
```